# What is the oldest copy of Genesis 26, and is there a place to see a side-by-side translation? thanks

Tags: genesis, old-testament, bible-translation, isaac

What is the oldest copy of Genesis 26, and is there a place to see a side-by-side translation? thank you!

Comment: [Link](http://greekdoc.com/polyglot/genesis26.html#v1).